# Extending classes with inner-classes (and also extending the inner-classes when going from one class to another) in java

Tags: java, inner-classes

I'm having problems with the relation between nested classes and subclasses. Consider the following code:

```
class Graph {
  class Edge {
    ...
  }

  class Vertex {
    List<Edge> _edges;
    ...
  }
  ...
}

class WeightedGraph extends Graph {
  class WeightedEdge extends Edge {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The thing is, when writing methods for WeightedGraph, I can't access _edges; the editor says it can't convert from type Edge to WeightedEdge. I think I must also extend the nested class Vertex, because in Graph it uses type Edge, and in WeightedGraph it must use type WeightedEdge. What would be a good way to do this (without writing the code all over again)?

Comment: Show how you are trying to access inner class fields.

Comment: You can't do `class WeightedEdge extends Edge`. Edge is an inner class of Graph, only visible within parent class(Graph).

Answer (score 2):

You have `_edges` declared as a member of `Graph.Vertex`. Only `Vertex` or its subclasses have that member. If you want your class to have it, you need to subclass `Vertex` too.

Edit: It sounds like you have an additional problem, with co and contravariance. The issue is that the base class is declared to contain a list with generic type `Edge`. While you can store `WeigtedEdges` in it, you won't be able to get them back without a cast, as all the compiler knows is that it contains regular `Edges`.

I don't remember the exact rules on generics, but I beleive that something along these lines might help. Alternatively, you could just bite the bullet and add the extra casts. The purpose of generics is to help add some extra compile time type checking, but when that gets in the way, you can just ignore it. The only risk is that it's easier for bugs to slip in since the type will only be checked at runtime.

```
class Vertex <T extends Edge> {
    List<T> _edges;
    ...
  }

class WeightedVertex extends Vertex<WeightedEdge> {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define methods for accessing class fields of the `Vertex` from `WeightedGraph`.

Something like:

```
class Graph
{
   ...
    protected List<Edge> getVertexEdges(Vertex v)
    {
        return v._edges;
    }
}
```

So you can use this helper in your subclasses